# Did Gaiman and Pratchett troll an interviewer who thought they were religious fanatics?

Tags: identification-request, neil-gaiman, terry-pratchett, good-omens

[TVTropes says](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Funny/GoodOmens), about the book *Good Omens*:

> In real life: Gaiman and Pratchett did a radio interview when the book came out, and slowly realized that the interviewer wasn't aware that the book was fictional, and thought they were a couple of religious kooks writing about what they thought would be the real apocalypse. They spent the rest of it viciously trolling him.

This sounds hilarious, but there's no citation for it. Is it true, and, if so, who, when, and where? Is a recording or transcription of this interview available?

Comment: I asked Neil Gaiman to comment via Twitter  (https://twitter.com/ardispark/status/1353467693245083649).

Comment: I used some different search terms than the ones that led to my answer; just found a [cross-site duplicate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/213908). SF&F hasn't found a transcript or recording.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I haven't found a transcript or recording of that interview, but I did find a [transcript of a different interview](https://www.locusmag.com/2006/Issues/1991_Gaiman_Pratchett.html) where the two spoke about that interview:

> Neil Gaiman: "The first radio interview we did in New York, the interviewer was asking us 'Who is Agnes Nutter? What is her history? Is Armageddon happening?" and so on and so forth. After a while, we twigged he hadn't realized this was fiction. He thought he'd been given two kooks who'd come across these old prophecies and were predicting that the world was going to be ending."
>
> Terry Pratchett: "Once we realized, it was great fun. We could take over the interview, since we knew he didn't know enough to stop us."

More links confirming that this occurred (stolen from an [a very similar question on SF&F.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/213908)):

- a mention of the interview in a [reprinted edition of *Good Omens*](https://archive.org/details/goodomens00neil_2/page/383/mode/2up)
- a mention of the interview on [Neil Gaiman's blog](https://journal.neilgaiman.com/2002/08/so-i-did-minneapolis-public-radios-all.asp)
- a [Neil Gaiman interview in 2015](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2015/mar/23/neil-gaiman-remembers-terry-pratchett-michael-chabon-interview):

  > “[Terry] said ‘Well, you remember we were on the Good Omens author tour in February 1990’ … He said ‘We were in New York and we went to that ABC affiliate radio station, and the interviewer had not actually read the book … so when we started telling him about Agnes Nutter … we started explaining about this 17th century witch who all of her predictions were true … He did not realise this was fictional. We realised he had not read the book, and the engineers in the control room behind the glass panel who we could see and he could not, were lying on their backs kicking their legs against the walls.’
  >
  > And I said, ‘Of course I remember. I was willing to let that go on for the entire interview’.

To answer the title: **Yes, this interview occurred**. No transcript or recording appears to be available, however. (Also, go upvote [Jos's answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/17262/11259) - they got confirmation from Gaiman himself!)

Comment: Thanks, that's good info. I might not accept this without more information about the original interview, but it's definitely worth an upvote for answering the title question. (Unless they were making it up for a funny story, of course ...)

Answer (score 61):

I asked Mr Gaiman on Twitter to respond, and he did, as well as another person:

Aliza "I think and I vote." (@alizatw):

> To summarize: it's reported but not authoritatively confirmed that
> @neilhimself and @terryandrob did a radio interview with someone who
> thought they were religious zealots and #GoodOmens was talking about
> the real Armageddon.

[Neil Gaiman (@neilhimself)](https://twitter.com/neilhimself/status/1353670551710130176):

> There are dozens of interviews with us about this and it's even
> mentioned in the afterword to one of the current editions. He didn't
> think we were religious looks, just that we believed in Agnes and her
> prophecies.

[image: transcription above]

Comment: Great, thanks for the authoritative response! I wonder if the "*They spent the rest of it viciously trolling him*" on TVTropes is as much editorialising as the "*religious kooks*". In [this interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=1503&v=CPBetz7p3fQ&feature=youtu.be) (which Gallifreyan found for me in chat), it seems that NG was "willing to let it go on the entire interview" but TP said "I had to put him out of his misery". Did they actually troll him through the whole interview, or did they explain the truth to him during it?

Comment: For completeness's sake, the current edition is probably the Harper paperback, which (on pg. 383) describes "the moment, live on air, when we realized that an underinformed New York radio interviewer with ten minutes of chat still to go *thought* Good Omens *was not a work of fiction*." (Emphasis in original.)